# understand iOS crash log

Tags: ios, crash

Could someone please help me understand this crash report. I can't make head or tail of it.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  8

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec73fce __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3983dcca objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec73ea8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 96
3   Foundation                      0x2f620d56 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 86
4   UIKit                           0x314bce9a -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] + 166
5   UIKit                           0x314cdaf4 -[UIKeyboardImpl prepareForSelectionChange] + 88
6   UIKit                           0x314afe10 -[UIFieldEditor setAttributedText:andSetCaretSelectionAfterText:] + 52
7   UIKit                           0x314cd77a -[UIFieldEditor setText:andSetCaretSelectionAfterText:] + 130
8   UIKit                           0x314cd508 -[UITextField setText:] + 220
9   UIKit                           0x316852c8 -[UISearchBar setText:] + 40
10  Farm Hand                       0x0009b906 0x7000 + 608518
11  Foundation                      0x2f65ca5a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e69914 _pthread_body + 136
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e69886 _pthread_start + 98
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e67aa0 thread_start + 4


Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39deda58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ded854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec3e896 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec3d002 __CFRunLoopRun + 850
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2eba7f0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2eba7cee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   GraphicsServices                0x33acd65e GSEventRunModal + 134
7   UIKit                           0x314f3168 UIApplicationMain + 1132
8   Farm Hand                       0x0009de44 0x7000 + 618052
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x39d4aab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ded808 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x39d2f078 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x39d2edfe _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39deda58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39ded854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec3e896 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec3cfbc __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2eba7f0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2ebeb9fe CFRunLoopRun + 94
6   CoreMotion                      0x2f2653a8 ___lldb_unnamed_function1423$$CoreMotion + 724
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e69916 _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e69886 _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e67aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e00434 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec42758 __CFSocketManager + 480
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e69916 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e69886 _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e67aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39df11a8 kevent + 24
1   ExternalAccessory               0x2f58567a -[EAInputStream _readInputFromAccThread] + 382
2   Foundation                      0x2f65ca5a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e69916 _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e69886 _pthread_start + 98
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e67aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e00c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e67bda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e67a94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e00c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e67bda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e67a94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e00c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e67bda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e67a94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e001f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e6a792 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39db0fd8 abort + 72
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x390dfcd2 abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x390f86e0 default_terminate_handler() + 248
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3983df62 _objc_terminate() + 190
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x390f61c4 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x390f5a18 __cxa_throw + 112
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3983dd9e objc_exception_throw + 246
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2ec73ea8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 96
10  Foundation                      0x2f620d56 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 86
11  UIKit                           0x314bce9a -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] + 166
12  UIKit                           0x314cdaf4 -[UIKeyboardImpl prepareForSelectionChange] + 88
13  UIKit                           0x314afe10 -[UIFieldEditor setAttributedText:andSetCaretSelectionAfterText:] + 52
14  UIKit                           0x314cd77a -[UIFieldEditor setText:andSetCaretSelectionAfterText:] + 130
15  UIKit                           0x314cd508 -[UITextField setText:] + 220
16  UIKit                           0x316852c8 -[UISearchBar setText:] + 40
17  Farm Hand                       0x0009b908 0x7000 + 608520
18  Foundation                      0x2f65ca5a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e69916 _pthread_body + 138
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e69886 _pthread_start + 98
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e67aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00002060
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x04d2f000      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x04d2dd14
    r8: 0x1804a3c0    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x31ae10c8     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x04d2dd08      lr: 0x39e6a797      pc: 0x39e001f0
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

I'm using the ExternalAccessory framework which I've had problems with in the past and the App crashed whilst receiving data from a bluetooth connected external device. However, I can't tell if that was what caused the crash.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please symbolicate the crash report, frame #10 should show your own code. Also try to get the exception reason, probably the easiest way is to test while attaching the debugger to the device. Also note that `UIKeyboardTaskQueue` is raising an exception because you doing something wrong. In addition you are calling UIKit code in a background thread. Make sure the calls are actually thread safe.

Comment: I did symbolicate, and re-symbolicate many times but this is what xcode gives me, hence why i came to stack overflow. I cannot recreate the crash when the device is connected to the debugger, which is also why I wanted help understanding the report.

Comment: To symbolicate your apps own calls you need the dSYM that was created alongside the exact build that caused this crash. The Xcode symbolication tool needs the exact .app and .dSYM to be in the same directory and being found via Spotlight. Some more details on this can be found here: http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/how-to-solve-symbolication-problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash was caused by something that went wrong inside of:

```
 [UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished]
```

which was called in the process of executing:

```
[UISearchBar setText:]
```

So, it seems, you typed something in a search bar, and the app crashed.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys it appears I've been calling UIKit stuff not on the main thread as Kerni said. Hopefully that's all that caused the crash.